# Storybook: hide 'show code' button inside an Angular project

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

Do you know if is possible to remove the 'show code' button below the component?
because the output it's weird. I am using the package '@storybook/addon-docs'

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution for the above query?

Answer (score 2):

You could set docs > source > code to `null` like so:

```
export const StoryX= StoryXTemplate.bind({})
StoryX.parameters = {
  docs: {
    source: {
      code: null
    }
  }
}
```